# Unity: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to Build and Run my Unity Applikation. But i get the following error message:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Daniel/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Can please someone tell my what to do?

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: No, i dont. I found a solution though. I had to reset my sdk builder tools from version 24 to 20. No its running like a charm.